# division by zero warning in numpy despite there being no zeros to divide in a function for finding inverse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, oop, matrix-inverse

I am making a function for a matrix class for finding the inverse matrix using gaussian elimination, The function works fine most of the time it would have random warnings that come in pairs that look like this

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

The problem comes for the lines where I divide everything in the same row by a constant. However, the first part of the function already makes sure the all the pivot elements in the matrix would not be zero. I have also ran a lot of tests and the problem isn't coming from the pivot elements being zero, the pivot elements are the only elements used for division, so I don't understand where the error is coming from

```
def inverse(self):
        if self.row != self.col:
            raise ValueError("Inverse Matrices only possible with square matrices")
        det = self.determinant()
        if det == 0:
            raise ValueError("The provided matrix does not have an Inverse")

        # Makes sure that the pivot elements are not zero
        inverse = Matrix.identity(self.row)
        placeHolder = [[self.matrix[i, j] for j in range(self.col)] for i in range(self.row)]
        for i in range(self.col):
            if self.matrix[i, i] == 0:
                for j in range(self.row):
                    if self.matrix[j, i] != 0:
                        for k in range(self.col):
                            self.matrix[i, k] += self.matrix[j, k]
                            inverse.matrix[i, k] += inverse.matrix[j, k]
                        break

        # Row operations
        for i in range(self.row):
            constant = self.matrix[i, i]
            for j in range(self.col):
                self.matrix[i, j] /= constant
                inverse.matrix[i, j] /= constant

            row = i
            while row != 0:
                constant = self.matrix[row-1, i]
                for j in range(self.col):
                    self.matrix[row-1, j] -= self.matrix[i, j] * constant
                    inverse.matrix[row-1, j] -= inverse.matrix[i, j] * constant
                row -= 1

            row = i
            while row != self.row - 1:
                constant = self.matrix[row+1, i]
                for j in range(self.col):
                    self.matrix[row+1, j] -= self.matrix[i, j] * constant
                    inverse.matrix[row+1, j] -= inverse.matrix[i, j] * constant
                row += 1

        self.set(placeHolder)
        return inverse
```

Comment: What is `double_scalars` and where is it called? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I am a bit new to programming so I am not too sure either, but I think double scalar means a float in numpy. Also should I include all the method used in this class as well as my test program, since this is my first time posting, I am not too sure about including so much

Comment: The loops range starts from 0 so they probably recompute `self.matrix[i, i]`. Is this normal? Isn't a `if i != j` required? By the way, note that if you have written this code so to learn how to implement a matrix inversion, this is Ok but if you plan to use this in a (real) project, please consider using Numpy/Numba/Cython instead as this code will certainly be ~1000 times slower than what Numpy should be able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While initially you check that the diagonal elements of a matrix are non-zero, these elements are modified as you perform row operations, and they may become zeros. A usual step in the row reduction of a matrix is to check that an element in a pivot position is non-zero before using it do modify other rows, since this cannot be determined beforehand.

As a side note, I don’t know how the function computing the determinant is implemented, but because floating point arithmetic is not exact, typically computations of a determinant can give a non-zero value even if matrix is singular. The same problem applies to row reduction of matrices: due to rounding errors these computations may give wrong results, with singular matrices appearing to be non-singular and vice versa. In numerical analysis there are a lot of considerations and methods that deal with such issues.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it turns out that was the exact issue that I overlooked.